# How to make new KVM with existing hard drive

Tags: virtualbox, kvm, qemu

I've been looking through the options of the QEMU binary, and I can't work this one out: Is it possible to make a new KVM machine with an existing hard drive image with an OS (XP Pro in this case) already installed?

I have seen a guide online to turn my VirtualBox XP Pro hard drive (.vdi) into a qemu image (which I have done) but I can't seem to make a new KVM using this existing hard drive?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
virt-install ... --disk [path to your existing image] --import ...
```

**--import**
Skip the OS installation process, and build a guest around an existing disk image. The device used for booting is the first device specified via "--disk" or "--file".

**--disk [path]**
path - A path to some storage media to use, existing or not. Existing media can be a file or block device. Specifying a non-existent path implies attempting to create the new storage, and will require specifyng a ’size’ value.

Comment: Ah, the import option, I didnt find this. Thanks so much :D

Answer (score 1):

`qemu-img` command can convert any img format.

You can convert `.vdi` image to raw image. All hypervisors support raw image format.
Then you can convert raw image to `qed`/`qcow2` format to save image size.

Comment: qemu-img command support vdi format.

Comment: qemu can directly run vdi format disk.